# Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjecture for algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Z}/m$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, motivic-cohomology

Let $X$ be smooth over some field $k$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $m$ maps to a unit in $k^{\times}$. By Beilinson-Lichtenbaum one has an isomorphism of cohomology groups
\begin{equation*}
    \operatorname{H}^{p,q}_{\operatorname{mot}}(X,\mathbb{Z}/m)\cong\operatorname{H}_{\operatorname{ét}}^{p}(X,\mu_{m}^{\otimes q})
\end{equation*}
as long as $q\geq p$. This gives an "étale interpretation" to the motivic cohomology of $X$ with values in $\mathbb{Z}/m$.

It is possible to define motivic cohomology with values in finite extensions of $\mathbb{Z}/m$.  For that purpose let $\operatorname{I}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}/m[x]$ be a prime ideal. Is it possible to give an "étale interpretation" to the cohomology groups
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{H}^{p,q}_{\operatorname{mot}}(X,\mathbb{Z}[x]/(m,\operatorname{I}))\text{?}
\end{equation*}

Comment: But the answer depends only on $\mathbb Z[x]/(m,I)$ as abelian group. But any finite abelian group is a sum of cyclic.